# Why do knownStates and Pulled states reset to zero on restarting geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I've noticed that, if I restart geth, attach a console and run `eth.syncing`, the `knownStates` and `pulledStates` values reset to zero and gradually increase again.

Possibly naively, I'd expect that, once known, the states should not be forgotten. Why am I seeing this behaviour?

Why do `knownStates` and `pulledStates` reset to zero on restarting geth (after running `eth.syncing`?

Answer (score 1):

This could be of help: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9116/4181 Short answer: This information is generated based on verification of the data available in your chaindata folder and is recalculated/verified every time your node client starts.

Comment: +1 thanks, but why is it re-calculated? Why not start from where it left off?

Comment: Basically, the client makes sure every block in the chain fits closely to it's neighbour and the data was not tampered with.