# Obtaining pulledStates from Geth

Tags: go-ethereum, state-trie

How to obtain `pulledStates` from Geth when `syncing` is `false`?

Comment: Do you mean getting the statistics (i.e. number) or the whole state structure?

Comment: When syncing is true, web3.eth.syncing returns syncing object, which includes `pulledStates` variable. I need that variable when syncing is false.

Comment: Some related links: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25620/how-to-access-geths-state-trie and https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9112/what-is-knownstates